How to Set Max Height of a Nested Grid with Images?
For the life of me, I cannot get this. All I want to do is have the max-height be equal to the grid-template-area but I am continuously getting overflow issues, things aren't centered, and the nested grid overflows the designated grid area.
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm very new to all of this and this is something I just cannot figure out. I'm sorry that my code is a mess. Any pointers there would be appreciated as well.
Explicitly, I want to set the nested grid area height to be equal and dynamic with the grid-template-area height.


* {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: minmax(845px, 66%) minmax(422px, 33%); 
    grid-template-rows: minmax(58px, 8%) minmax(58px, 8%) minmax(72px, 10%) minmax(475px, 66%) minmax(58px, 8%); 
    grid-template-areas: 
        "Header Header"
        "Nav Nav"
        "Settings Settings"
        "Course Stats"
        "Footer Footer";
    height: 720px;
    width: 1280px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.Header { 
    grid-area: Header; 
    background: teal;
}
.Nav { 
    grid-area: Nav; 
    background: salmon;
}
.Settings { 
    grid-area: Settings; 
    background: yellowgreen;
}
.Course {
    display: grid; 
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 40% 1fr 1fr 30%; 
    grid-template-rows: 15% repeat(3,1fr); 
    gap: 1vw 1vh; 
    grid-template-areas: 
        ". . . Class"
        "Console Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail"
        "Console Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail"
        "Console Thumbnail Thumbnail Thumbnail"; 
    grid-area: Course; 
    background: brown;
}
.Console {
    grid-area: Console;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-content: center;
}
.Class { 
    grid-area: Class; 
    background: blue;
}
.Thumbnail { 
    grid-area: Thumbnail; 
    background: purple;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.Stats { 
    grid-area: Stats; 
    background: orange;
}
.Footer { 
    grid-area: Footer; 
    background: green;
}

/* Console Header */
.class-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 1.5vw 1.5vh;
    gap: 3vw 3vh;
    border: 5px solid black;
    align-items: center;
}

.class-icon img {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    opacity: 50%;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 80%;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
    }
}

.class-container input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.75));
    opacity: 100%;
}

#console-column {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.console-image img {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    opacity: 50%;
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: auto;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 80%;
        transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
    }
}

#console-column input[type=radio]:checked + .console-image img{
    opacity: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.75));
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out, filter 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Course Grid */
.course-container {
    display: grid;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5,1fr);
    background-color: cyan;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.5vw 1.5vh;
    grid-gap: 3vw 3vh;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.course-container > div img {
    display: block;
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
    opacity: 80%;
    border: 5px solid transparent;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 100%;
        transition: opacity 100ms ease-in-out;
    }
}
.course-container input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
    border: 5px solid salmon;
    background-color: salmon;
    opacity: 100%;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 4%, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 4%, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 4%, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 4%, gold 0);
    mask-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: 51% 51%;
}
<div class="Course">
  <h1>Course</h1>
  <div class="Console">
    <div id="console-column">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="console">
        <div class="console-image">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Class">
    <div class="class-container">
      <div class="class-icon">
        <input type="radio" name="class"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/120x120">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="class-icon">
        <input type="radio" name="class"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/120x120">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="class-icon">
        <input type="radio" name="class"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/120x120">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Thumbnail">
    <div class="course-container">
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="course-thumbnail gbaCourses">
        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail"/>
        <label>
          <img src="https://placehold.co/404x277">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Also, here's a link to the Github

Please edit your question to describe (in detail) your desired result and compare that with your actual result. Also, please explain why you're setting the body dimensions to a fixed value.

I simply want the bounding max height of the nested grid-area to be equal to the parent's inherit height, so it takes up 100% of the space. No more and no less. As for the body dimensions, I want to make sure everything looks good on a lower resolution before scaling. I do not know if this is the right way to do this, but the only way I've figured out that works as the Firefox responsive design app did not correctly show some css.
